# SQL 2017 - Configuration MSC - greyed-out Remove for Startup Param (have dupes)

Tags: sql-server-2017

I'm a local Admin, so rights don't appear to be the issue.

Hopefully the image shows that somehow, some time, duplicate file paths were added to the default instance start-up parameters.  I've tried to delete one of the two identical LOG entries - neither selection activates "Remove".

There are 2 master mdf and ldf specs...  Need to clean those up...  I **can** delete the -TF!  I need to add a few as that was overlooked by whomever.

Search engines give no on-subject items.  Search of this site yielded nothing either, despite may partial hits.

BOL isn't a great deal of help.

Anyone met, and more importantly, overcome this blocker, please?

[image: Current Startup Params]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Microsoft's documentation about that tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-properties-startup-parameters-tab?view=sql-server-2017), the -d, -l, and -e entries can not be removed.

> The following parameters are required. They can be changed but not removed.
>
> - -d is the path of the master.mdf file (the master database data file).
> - -l is the path of the master.ldf file (the master database log file).
> - -e is the path of the SQL Server error log files.

That doesn't solve your problem, but likely explains why the Remove button remains grayed out.

Because the GUI detects those as "protected", and thus won't enable the Remove button, you'll have to delete them via another method. If you are comfortable editing (and backing up) the registry, you can do it there. It's in here:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<Your Instance; probably "MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER">\MSSQLServer\Parameters
```